# Is there a way to extend a built-in type to inherit an interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance, built-in

I want to add an interface to some built-in types. I have an interface, `IConcludable`, which I am using as a constraint for `Conclusion<T>`. I have no clue how to approach this, or if it is even possible.

**Basic Layout**

```
public interface IConcludable { }

public struct Conclusion<T> where T : IConcludable
{
    public bool IsSuccessful;
    public T Result;

    // Constructors, members, etc.
}

public class ErrorReport : IConcludable { ... }

public class MathArg : IConcludable { ... }

public class ParseResult : IConcludable { ... }
```

**Implementation**

```
public Conclusion<ParseResult> ParseInput (string input)
{
    // Parse input...
    // Initialize ParseResult object...

    return new Conclusion<ParseResult>(result);
}
```

**Problem**

When I get the final value, it is a built-in type like `int`, `double`, `string`, `bool`, etc. I would like to use `Conclusion<T>` as a return because I have a class that handles error reports when the input string is invalid:

```
if (conclusion.ReturnObject is ErrorReport)
{
    ErrorManager errorManager = new ErrorManager();
    errorManager.Resolve(conclusion);
}
```

**Research**

I looked into *constraints*.

- [Is there a C# generic constraint for “real number” types? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348594/is-there-a-c-sharp-generic-constraint-for-real-number-types)

It appears that constraints only add together, so including the interfaces of each built-in type that I need would require defining a mountain of methods that do not have anything to do with my `Conclusion` struct.

*Extension methods*

- [How to extend C# built-in types, like String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910108/how-to-extend-c-sharp-built-in-types-like-string)

These actually change the behavior of built-in types. It is not what I am looking for because my interface, `IConcludable`, does not have any methods.

*Replacing built-in types*

- [Overwrite built in .NET class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844583/overwrite-built-in-net-class)

Not possible. I don't need to change the behavior of these types though. I just want to add an empty interface to it.

There does not seem to be anything regarding adding an interface to a built-in type. I'm not sure if "Inheritance" is what it would be referred to. Is this possible?

**Edit**

*Better explanation of Conclusion struct*

I am using the conclusion struct as a return object in most of my methods. This is because I am using delegates. See the actual code of the objects below:

```
public delegate Conclusion<T> Validator<T>(T subclass) where T : IVerifiable<T>;

public delegate Conclusion<BaseFunction> Executor(BaseFunction subclass);

public struct Conclusion<T> where T : IConcludable
{
    public bool IsSuccessful;
    public T ReturnObject;

    public Conclusion(T returnObject)
    {
        this.ReturnObject = returnObject;
        this.IsSuccessful = returnObject is Error ? false : true;
    }
}

public class BaseFunction : IVerifiable<BaseFunction>, IConcludable
{
    public List<BaseArgument> Args;
    public Executor Executing;
    public Validator<BaseFunction> Validating;
    public string UserInput;

    public Conclusion<BaseFunction> Validate(BaseFunction subclass)
    {
        if (this.Validating != null)
        {
            return Validating(subclass);
        }
        else
        {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            message.Append("A Validating delegate has not been assigned.");

            throw new InvalidOperationException(message.ToString());
        }
    }

    public Conclusion<BaseFunction> Execute(BaseFunction subclass)
    {
        if (this.Executing != null)
        {
            return this.Executing(subclass);
        }
        else
        {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            message.Append("An Executing delegate has not been assigned.");

            throw new InvalidOperationException(message.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public class Function<T> : BaseFunction
{
    public T Result;

    public Function()
    {
        base.Args = new List<BaseArgument>();
    }
}

public class BaseArgument : IVerifiable<BaseArgument>, IConcludable
{
    public string Role;
    public string UserInput;
    public int Position;
    public Validator<BaseArgument> Validating;

    public Conclusion<BaseArgument> Validate(BaseArgument subclass)
    {
        if (this.Validating != null)
        {
            return Validating(subclass);
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}

public class Argument<T> : BaseArgument
{
    public T Value;

    public Argument(int position)
    {
        base.Position = position;
    }
}

public static class ExecutionHandler
{
    public static Conclusion<BaseFunction> Sum(BaseFunction subclass)
    {
        subclass = (Function<double>)subclass;

        // Execution code.

        return new Conclusion<BaseFunction>(subclass);
    }

    public static Conclusion<BaseFunction> Concatenate(BaseFunction subclass)
    {
        subclass = (Function<double>)subclass;

        // Execution code.

        return new Conclusion<BaseFunction>(subclass);
    }
}
```

If I need to post more, I will. but it's really a lot to look at. The return type of the methods assigned by all of the delegates I use have a return type of `Conclusion<T>` so that I can have a return object as well as an error if one occurs. The functions in the code above return `Conclusion<BaseFunction>`, but that return is converted into an object `Addend<T>` if it is a number. If it is a part of another type of function that returns a `string` or `bool` or other type, it is converted into a different type of class. By the end of a numeric calculation, the return will be something like `Conclusion<int>` or `Conclusion<double>`. So adding `int` and `double` to the `IConcludable` interface is what I am trying to do.

*Better explanation of the application*

I am writing a C# console application. It takes input from the user, and writes an answer. The input is similar to Excel formulas: `Sum(5, 15, Average(2, 3), 5)` or `Concatenate("5 + 5 = ", Text(Sum(5, 5)))`. The input string is validated, parsed, and returns a result.

Comment: as I see in your implementation, you're returning Conclusion<T>. But you also said ***When I get the final value, it is a built-in type like int, double, string, bool, etc***, I don't understand this part.

Comment: Although your question is very well put, I think you should sharpen the *actual question* you have, as currently it isn't clear what isn't working with this construct.

Comment: Isn't it scenario for **Adapter pattern**?

Comment: @kienct89 : I'll post an edit to the question to explain it better. Thanks.

Comment: @LeiYang : I'm not sure what an Adapter pattern is.. I still kind of new to programming. It's a C# console app that reads an input line, and parses it to produce a result, and displays it back to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED (ADD MORE EXPLANATION)**

As requested, I want to explain a bit more about my last answer.

*Requirements*

- The `Conclusion` need to support both **value type and reference type**
- Generic
- Value Types: all numeric data types (int, short, long, etc), boolean, char, date....
- Reference Types: string and user-defined class (in OP's sample, **`IConcludable`**)

*Solution:*

- Introduce a base class (`AbstractConclusion`) that accepts `Object` as generic input
- Move the logic to base class for reuse
- Introduce two new concrete implementations that accepts `struct` and `IConcluable` (have the ability to add more implementation, for ex: string)
- The inherited classes are able to all the methods of base class

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

You can put the logic in `AbstractConclusion` class, and have two implementations of it (`Conclusion` which accepts `IConcludeable` and `PrimitiveConclusion` which accepts `struct` data type)

See code sample below:

```
void Main()
{
    PrimitiveConclusion<int> primitiveConclusion = new PrimitiveConclusion<int>(1);
    Conclusion<ParseResult> parseResultConclusion = new Conclusion<ParseResult>(new ParseResult {});

    Console.WriteLine($"{primitiveConclusion.Result.GetType()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{parseResultConclusion.Result.GetType()}");
}

public class TestClass
{
    public Conclusion<ParseResult> ParseInput(string input)
    {
        return new Conclusion<ParseResult>(null);
    }
}

public interface IConcludable { }

public abstract class AbstractConclusion<T>
{
    public AbstractConclusion(T t)
    {
        IsSuccessful = t != null;
        Result = t;
    }
    public bool IsSuccessful;
    public T Result;
}

public class Conclusion<T> : AbstractConclusion<T> where T : IConcludable
{
    public Conclusion(T t) : base(t)
    {
    }
}


public class PrimitiveConclusion<T> : AbstractConclusion<T> where T : struct
{
    public PrimitiveConclusion(T t) : base(t)
    {
    }
}


public class ParseResult : IConcludable { }
```

Comment: kienct89, I'm trying to understand what the abstract class is doing. It seems like it would accept any value. Like `T` is equivalent to `object`. Is that what the abstract class is for in your example? Thanks.

Comment: @TylerPantuso: `AbstractConclusion` is just a base class to group all the similar functionalities of Conclusion so you do not need to rewrite for all child classes. For the second part of your question, it should accept all types (in order to support primitive, int and IConcluable).

Comment: Wouldn't `IConcludable` need to be removed completely?

Comment: @TylerPantuso: the `Conclusion` class still using `IConcluable`, only the `AbstractConclusion` is not using.

Comment: Great solution! I suggested an edit that paraphrases your work. It is to provide a general answer to the main question. I'll accept it then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With `where T : IConcludable` generic type constraint you can not pass `int` as generic argument. And also there is no way to append an interface to primitive type.

You can do some workaround to do this. You can put the main logic of `Conclusion` into base abstract class and inherit from it, restructure `Conclusion` as `class` (because `struct`s not support inheritance) and create classes

```
public class Conclusion<T> : BaseConclusion
where T : IConcludable
```

and

```
public class PrimitiveConclusion<T> : BaseConclusion
where T : struct
```

and also you should create another class for `string`, as `string` is not struct and not implement `IConcludable`

As I know, there is no another way to pass different types as generic arguments.

---

Also, instead of creating `Conclusion` class for built-in types you can create wrapper struct, which will implement `IConcludable`. And have a deal with it

```
public struct Wrapper<T> : IConcludable
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```